# I have more than 3k rows of data to retrieve from cassandra using an api. I have indexing on it but its causing issue of connection reset

Tags: cassandra

I have more than 3k rows of data to retrieve from cassandra using an api. I have indexing on it but then also its causing issue of connection reset.

Should I look for any other data base to do so?

Is it possible to have a work around in cassandra?

Will providing limit or filter on between dates in query will help?
(so there will be restriction on api, is it standard practice)

Answer (score 1):

So there's a lot missing here that is needed to help diagnose what is going on.  Specifically, it'd be great to see the underlying table definition and the actual CQL query that the API is trying to run.

Without that, I can say that to me, it *sounds* like the API is trying to aggregate the 3000 rows from multiple partitions with a specific date range in the cluster (and is probably using the `ALLOW FILTERING` directive to accomplish this).  Most multi-partition queries will time-out, just because of all the extra network time being introduced while polling each node in the cluster.

As with all queries in Cassandra, a table needs to be built to support a specific query.  If it's not, this is generally what happens.

> Will providing limit or filter on between dates in query will help?

Yes, breaking this query up into smaller pieces will help.  If you can look at the underlying table definition, that might give you a clue as to the right way to properly query the table.  But in this case, making 10 queries for 300 rows probably has a higher chance for success than 1 query for 3000 rows.